# Rails passing parent id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing, one-to-many

I have a UserStory model and a Task model and i want to let users add task to the user story dynamically what i'm about is passing the user story id to the tasks create action could anybody help me please?

user_stories/show

```
<%= link_to "Add new task",{:controller => ':tasks', :action => :new},:user_story_id: = >@user_story.id, remote: true %>
```

tasks/new.js.erb

```
$('#new_task_link').hide().after('<%= j render :partial => "form" %>');
```

and the tasks/_form

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_story_id, :value => params[:user_story_id] %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nest your tasks resources under your user_stories resources in config/routes.rb:

```
resources :user_stories do
  resources: tasks
end
```

Your link then becomes:

```
<%= link_to "Add new task", user_story_tasks_path(@user_story.id) %>
```

In the TasksController, you'll now have access to `:user_story_id` in the `params`.

A [Rails Cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources) covers this. It's a bit outdated (`map` is no longer necessary in config/routes.rb), but the fundamental concept is still the same.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, i modified my routes and made the add task link like that    <%= link_to "Add new task", new_user_story_task_path(@user_story.id) %> and it reditects me to the tasks/new what i really want is to make this form appear in the same page as user_stories/show but when i add remote: true to this link it doesnot work

Comment: That gets a bit more involved. Here's the associated Rails Cast that handles [nested forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) - revised episode requires $9 pro account, but I'm sure the free original episode will give the gist.